# Why is my template not getting view data from one func?

Tags: django

I have created a simple app for file upload. Everything worked fine.Then I wanted to add simple login and now I have problems.
These are my views

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user is active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form=LoginForm()

    return render(request,'account/login.html',{'form': form})



def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,'list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

This is fileupload/urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from fileupload.views import list
from fileupload.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', list, name='list'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
]
```

My forms

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

When I go to 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/fileupload/list/
everything works fine.
If I try
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
I got this
[image]

I am confused becuase template is getting data from one fun and not from the other.
How to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that you and list and login in the URL should go after http://127.0.0.1:8000/fileupload/

Try check http://127.0.0.1:8000/fileupload/login/

Read this docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/